# What is the best place to learn Iphone development with Xcode and objective-C basics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When I say best place, I mean a physical courses, seminars, workshops, etc...
It could be all around the world

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good [web source](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php) that you can access from anywhere in the world where there is web access.

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid seminaries for learning Objective-C.

I have heard good things about the [Big Nerd Ranch](http://www.bignerdranch.com/) courses.

Comment: Ha ha, nice, sorry, I think I ruined your joke by editing the post.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I've recently discovered are all of the Stamford lectures that are available on iTunes for free.  There is a tremendous number of lectures that have been published for free that have incredibly detailed information.

EDIT:  I guess I should mention that there was an entire semester long class on iPhone development that is on iTunes too.  The devil is in the details.

Answer (score 1):

I attended the Pragmatic Programmer's iPhone Studio several months ago.  The class is taught by Bill Dudney and Daniel Steinberg.  They were both excellent teachers and provided a good balance between lecture and lab time (and were very patient explaining the same thing over and over to me until I got it!).