# I need help to learn iPhone app development?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best place to learn Iphone development with Xcode and objective-C basics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927186/what-is-the-best-place-to-learn-iphone-development-with-xcode-and-objective-c-bas)

I need help to learn iPhone application development. Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start development of iPhone applications you must start to view some sources of other applications, but you must have some base knowledges in C++, Objective-C or C# because without that knowledges you cant start development. If you know one of this languages you can start development ... You can search some code examples and use [this](http://developer.apple.com/). I start my first program with help of documentation ... You must try hard ... Good Luck !!!

1. [Tutorial: The Objective-C Language](http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/05/04/cocoa.html)
2. [YouTube video: Xcode 3 Beep Tutorial](http://youtube.com/watch?v=y2MSvZT3zWU)
3. [YouTube video: Xcode 3 Beep Tutorial Part 2: Outlets](http://youtube.com/watch?v=pH9oHJpfSXU)
4. [Wikibooks: Programming Mac OS X with Cocoa for beginners](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programming_Mac_OS_X_with_Cocoa_for_beginners)

Answer (score 2):

I started by reading the great "Beginning iPhone Development" Book (see [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023024X)) and parallel to it I created a really small application. And when I was trapped in problems the Apple tutorials are also a great resource. But the important thing is to start with a really simple app, which you really want to get into the application store. That give motivation. :)

Answer (score 2):

I learned Objective C and iOS development with [Stanford University CS 193P classes](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) : videos, slideshows, and exercices. For me it's the best resource ever. After that you'll only need Google, the Apple Documentation, and a bit of StackOverflow to solve little issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read a book or online tutorial. There are literally hundreds of such resources, and this will assist you in understanding how to write iPhone apps, and give you ideas for projects. For getting started, it doesn't matter which book you choose - the basics are all the same.

Comment: nice but reading books are really time spending i know books are really good source of information but i need project base learning not just theory. i need a book in which more the practice include and less theory.